# In java, how do I make a class with a private constructor whose superclass also has a private constructor?

Tags: java, constructor

As an example:

```
public class Foo {
    private Foo() {}
}

public class Bar extends Foo {
    private Bar() {}

    static public doSomething() {
    }
}
```

That's a compilation error right there. A class needs to, at least, implicitly call its superclass's default constructor, which in this case is isn't visible in *Foo*.

Can I call *Object*'s constructor from *Bar* instead?

Comment: Is there a reason for Foo(){} being private instead of being protected?

Comment: @svelil: Let's say it's in a third party library, or otherwise outside my control, and I want to subclass it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't.  You need to make Foo's constructor package private at the very least (Though I'd probably just make it protected.

(Edit - Comments in this post make a good point)

Comment: Package-private is sufficient, if both are put in the same package.

Comment: @starblue - I believe that's why he said 'at the very least'.

Comment: package is more restrictive that protected, so 'at the very least' is wrong. If both were in the same outer class, I think the private construct would be accessible.

Answer (score 7):

This is actually a symptom of a bad form of inheritance, called implementation inheritance. Either the original class wasn't designed to be inherited, and thus chose to use a private constructor, or that the entire API is poorly designed.

The fix for this isn't to figure out a way to inherit, but to see if you can compose the object instead of inheriting, and do so via interfaces. I.e., class Foo is now interface Foo, with a FooImpl. Then interface bar can extend Foo, with a BarImpl, which has no relation to FooImpl.

Inside BarImpl, you could if you wish to do some code reuse, have a FooImpl inside as a member, but that's entirely up to the implementation, and will not be exposed.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to create an instance of Bar for as long as Foo has a private constructor. The only way you would be able to do it is if Foo had a protected constructor.

Comment: If a superclass has a private constructor, then the subclass won't even compile.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call Object's constructor directly from Bar while it's a subclass of Foo, it would have to through Foo's constructor, which is private in this case.

When you declare Foo's constructor private, it does not create a default public constructor.  Since Bar *has* to invoke Foo's constructor, it is not possible to leave it private.  I would suggest, as others have, on using protected instead of private.