# Accessing constructor from abstract base class with reflection

Tags: java, reflection, constructor

I'm playing around with Java's Reflection. I have an abstract class `Base` with a constructor.

```
abstract class Base {
    public Base( String foo ) {
        // do some magic
    }
}
```

I have some further classes extending `Base`. They don't contain much logic. I want to instantiate them with `Base`'s constructor, without having to write some proxy contructors in those derived classes. And of course, I want to instantiate those derived classes with Reflection. Say:

```
Class cls = SomeDerivedClass.class;
Constructor constr;
constr = cls.getConstructor( new Class[] { String.class } ); // will return null
Class clsBase = Base.class;
constr = clsBase.getConstructor( new Class[] { String.class } ); // ok
Base obj = (Base) constr.newInstance( new Object[] { "foo" } ); // will throw InstantiationException because it belongs to an abstract class
```

Any ideas, how I can instantiate a derived class with Base's constructor? Or *must* I declare those dumb proxy constructors?

Comment: Before instanciating those class are you sure everything is compiling?

Comment: Yes, it compiles fine. This is a simplified example, it lacks those  catch-clauses, but basically this code compiles fine. Ah, and `Base` has an additional empty default constructor (javac insisted on that).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A class does not inherit constructors from it parent.  A class does not have it parents constructors (though it can call them) So you have to call the constructors the class has, not a constructor a super class has.

The default constructor only appears to do this because it calls the default constructor of the parent by default.  If the parent doesn't have a default constructor, neither can its immediate children.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid your subclasses won't even compile until you have an explicit constructor in them calling one of the super() constructors.

Comment: Everything compiles fine. `Base(String)` does not get called in any subclass. But I had to define an empty default constructor for `Base` once.

Comment: That is a crucial difference though. It means that your child classes will compile ans instantiate, but will only call the empty parent constructor. There's no way you can access the other constructor, unless the child classes are explicitly calling it in their constructors.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot construct an abstract class without specifying all of the details that will make it "non-abstract".

That means in the example:

```
public abstract class Parent {
  String name;

  public Parent(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  abstract public String getName();

}
```

no amount of constructor manipulating via reflection will return a Parent-only class.  You can however, return an "anonymous" class by specifying the abstract details at construction time, like so:

```
Parent parent = new Parent() {
    public String getName() { return "Bob"; }
  };
```

Remember, sub-classing also calls the parent constructor, even if you don't put the code in explicitly.  A sub-class written like:

```
public class Child extends Parent {
  public Child(String name) {
  }
}
```

will look for a no arg constructor in the `Parent` class.  If it finds one, then it will be compiled into code equivalent to

```
public class Child extends Parent {
  public Child(String name) {
    super();
  }
}
```

If it doesn't find a no argument constructor in the `Parent` class, it will fail to compile until you explicitly specify the parent class construction with the `super(name);` constructor call.

Another thing to remember, all classes are subclasses of `Object`, so if you don't provide an `extends SomeClass` like so:

```
public class JustMe {
}
```

The compiler conceputally "corrects" you code at compile time to:

```
public class JustMe extends Object {

   public JustMe() {
     super();
   }
}
```

The Object class has a bunch of native (non-Java) code within it to register with the JVM ensuring correct garbage collection, memory management, type enforcement, etc. are followed over the life of the Object.

ie.  You can't get around it, the JVM will stop you from constructing and abstract class unless all of it's methods can be resolved via anonymous classes or subclasses.

Comment: Subclassing doesn't implicitly call anything but the no-parameter parent constructor, if one exists. It definitely won't pass parameters on by itself. Furthermore, if the abstract class' constructor requires a parameter, you should specify it when you create an anonymous class too, so the anon example should read: new Parent( "foo" ) { ... }

Comment: @biziclop Thank you for the excellent observation, post corrected for posterity's sake

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your base class constructor is nondefault (has a parameter). Thus it can't be called implicitly by a generated default subclass constructor. (In fact you should get a compilation warning/error about this.) I am afraid you need to add explicit subclass constructor(s).

Comment: I didn't get any warnings. Maybe because `Base` and the derived classes reside in different packages, located in different Eclipse projects.